# Is Tab Bar Controller allowed to be contained by navigation controller in modern iOS?

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios9, xcode7

Back in the days Apple says that Tab Bar Controller is not allowed to be contained in a Navigation Controller, possibly due to the fact that Tab Bar Controller can also contain Navigation Controller.  In an app where Tab Bar Controller and Navigation Bar Controller are both present, Tab Bar Controller always needs to be at the root.

Nowadays with Storyboard, it's possible to push a Tab Bar View Controller into a Navigation Controller via a Show segue.  Does that mean this rule is no longer applies in modern iOS SDK?

Answer (score 0):

I thought I read somewhere in the docs that the tab bar controller should always be the root view controller of an app. (Unfortunately, I can't find this article.) Furthermore, Xcode does not allow one to select a tab bar controller and then select Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller. This is likely Apple discouraging the developer from doing it.

So yes, I believe the rule still applies: having the Tab Bar Controller contained inside a Navigation Controller is **possible but discouraged** in the modern SDK.

The real question is **why would you want to do this?** If it's to make a login screen for the app and then push the tab bar controller once the user logs in, for example, it's justifiable to embed the tab bar controller. (though I personally prefer to do this with a modal segue)

Take a look at the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines regarding tabs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Bars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH12-SW52). If the tab bar is implemented in such a way that it does not *"organize information at the app level"*, then a tab bar shouldn't be used, simply because iOS users expect the tab bar to let them navigate the main features of the app.

Comment: My app starts out with a walkthrough + location screen. The walkthrough is embedded in a navigation controller, then the last step of walkthrough will push in the main thing, which is a tab bar controller.  As far as I can tell, storyboard allows the showing of tab bar controller with no issue, unless the show segue to tab bar controller does not actually add the tab bar controller to the navigation stack.

Comment: Great, so it adheres to the guidelines as I mentioned and isn't glitchy, therefore I would say that it is "allowed".

Comment: But it does generate the question of why in storyboard we can actually push a tab bar controller into a navigation controller, even though in code this is not encouraged.

Comment: Good point, but not recommended does not equal not possible. A random example: changing the size of a UIPickerView.